# In The Raven Tower, does the machinery that Oissen has built somehow increase a god's power?

Tags: the-raven-tower

In Ard Vusktia,

> the Strength and Patience of the Hill

asks Oissen the healer to build a device that will constantly turn it. Is this machine just a standard

> millstone

or does the mechanism somehow increase the god's power, without using prayers or offerings?